# Interchanging limit and integral verification

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

In some stuff I have this step:
$$\lim_{g\to 0}\int_0^1\bigg(\frac{1-x^{\frac{g}{1+g}}}{\frac{g}{1+g}}\bigg)^ndx=\int_0^1\bigg(\lim_{g\to 0}\frac{1-x^{\frac{g}{1+g}}}{\frac{g}{1+g}}\bigg)^ndx$$
where $n$ is some not so important parameter.
I'd like to show that this step IS actually valid. What I have to show is that $f_g(x)=\frac{1-x^{\frac{g}{1+g}}}{\frac{g}{1+g}}$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. But I'm confused about WHAT to limit, where, what to maximize. The definition says:
Sequence of functions $f_n$ converges uniformly on some interval $I$ to $f$ iff
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in I}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$
This confuses me, do I limit the $g$ to infinity, or to zero?... Thanks for any useful tips, links and hints.
My further steps:

Let $t=\frac{g}{1+g}$, thus $f_t(x)=\frac{1-x^t}{t}$ we also know that $\lim_{t\to 0}f_t(x)=-\ln{x}$. Now let $g_t(x)=\frac{1-x^t}{t}+\ln{x}$ we are to find $$\sup_{0\le x\le 1}{g_t(x)}=\max\{g_t(0),g_t(1),g_t(x_0)\}=g_t(1)$$ where $g'(x_0)=0$ is $x_0=1$. Thus we have $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\sup_{0\le x \le 1}|g_t(x)|=\lim_{t\to\infty}|0|=|0|=0$$ thus integrand converges uniformly and thus the step of interchanging limit and integral is valid. IS that correct?

Comment: Why don't you compute the limit for a fixed $x \neq 0$? Also, why not simplify your life and replace ${g \over 1+g}$ by $g$?

Comment: I am not interested in computing the limit, I am interested in the step of interchanging the limit and integral.

Comment: Ok, good luck to you then.

Comment: I am curious how you are going to show uniform convergence without knowing the limit (which is straightforward to compute).

Comment: Well, I know the limit is $\ln{x}$

Comment: You don't have uniform convergence. You can see this by noticing $f_t$ is a bounded function for each $t>0,$ but the pointwise limit function of $f_t(x)$ is $-\ln x,$ which is unbounded. I believe the desired result still holds. Do you know the dominated convergence theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have uniform continuity, as @zhw. points out in the comments, but it is a straightforward application of the dominated convergence theorem and a little convex observation.

If $f$ is concave, then $f'(0) \ge {f(t)-f(0)\over t} \ge f'(t)$. (See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable,
for example.)

For $x \in (0,1]$, the
function $f(t) = - x^t = - e^{t \log x}$ is concave, hence
$-\log x \ge {1-x^t \over t} \ge 0$.

Hence $({1-x^t \over t})^n \le |\log x|^n$.

It is straightforward to check that $\int_0^1 (\log x)^n dx = (-1)^n n!$.

Furthermore, for $x \in (0,1]$, $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} {1-x^t \over t} = - \log x$.

The dominated convergence theorem shows that
$\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \int_0^1 ({1-x^t \over t})^n dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{t \downarrow 0} ({1-x^t \over t})^n dx = \int_0^1 (- \log x)^n dx = n!$.

**Aside**:

Using integration by parts, we get
$\int_0^1 \log x dx = (x \log x) \mid_0^1 - \int_0^1 1dx = -1$, and
$\int_0^1 (\log x)^n dx = (x (\log x)^n) \mid_0^1 - n\int_0^1 (\log x)^{n-1}dx = -n \int_0^1 (\log x)^{n-1}dx$. Induction shows that
$\int_0^1 (\log x)^n dx = (-1)^n n!$.

Comment: Would you please explain, how did you come up with a bound $f'(0)\geq \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t}\geq f'(t)$?

Comment: Also, how do I check that $\int_0^1(\log{x})^ndx=(-1)^n n!$, because the steps I do bring me to this result, so it would be circular reasoning in that sense.

Comment: So, it seems you are interested in conputing the limit.

Comment: Well, of course I am, but thats not something i didnt manage to do. I actually did, but i wanted to know the reason why i could proceed how i proceeded - interchanging the limit and the integral signs.

Comment: The secant bounds come from concavity (or convexity, depending on your perspective). I added an inductive proof of the formula for the integral of $x \mapsto (\log x)^n$.